# How can I configure my css so that a span's height matches the adjacent input's height (Hubspot)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's the result that I'm trying to fix:

[image]

As you can see, the span with the percent symbol is stretching to fit the margin that is on the input. How can I prevent this? I've tried multiple css attributes but can't seem to break the span out of taking on the input's excess margin.

This is created using Hubspot CMS and I've had to try and recreate the bootstrap styling on my normal site.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="monthly-traffic" class="control-label">Monthly traffic (unique visitors)</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="monthly-traffic" id="monthly-traffic" class="form-control" placeholder="monthly traffic">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="percent-us" class="control-label">Percent of traffic from US</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input id="percent-us-addon" class="form-control" type="number" name="percent-us" placeholder="US traffic percentage" aria-describedby="percent-us-addon">
              <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and the css for:

```
col-sm-6: {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


input-group: {
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
form-control: {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out; 
}
```

and

```
input-group-addon:{
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: 1. I presume this is not the CSS you're using because the selectors are not declared properly. 2. The classes are bootstrap classes so are you using Bootstrap - if yes why are you redeclaring the CSS, and if not why not, when you're clearly need what it does. And 3. the code above doesn't reproduce the problem you describe. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem so that we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is missing the `.input-group` wrapper and the appropriate addon classes (`.input-group-append` and `.input-group-text`).

With this markup, you should not need any custom CSS at all:

```html
  <label for="percent-us" class="control-label">Percent of traffic from US</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="percent-us-addon" class="form-control" type="number" name="percent-us" placeholder="US traffic percentage" aria-describedby="percent-us-addon">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Full codepen @ https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/ywbjxZ